# Add Build Numbers via VS2010 when in Release Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild-4.0

I am trying to add a build release number to a component in my software solution and I have tried incrementing the number in the Assembly Info.cs class but this is not working.

To add a bit of context our build server is not available due to the host dying on us and we are waiting for a fix. So to keep going, we are trying to build locally in visual studio 2010  in Release mode. The code is building, but the build number appled to the assemblyinfo class is not showing when you install the component. It comes up as 0.0.0.1 rather than 1.0.0.24 for example.

So, how do you get it to use the build number?

Comment: by component you mean a msi component?

Comment: Sorry, I mean an msi

Comment: that depends on the installer package you use. there should be a component version table which you can alter